# PowerShell get TotalPhysicalMemory (RAM) without decimals

Tags: script, powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to inventory some info about computers (CPU, RAM, HDD, etc...). Everything is working quite well, but I'm stuck at getting the right output for the amount of RAM.

Here is what I currently have :

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName localhost).TotalPhysicalMemory/1Gb
```

This will return a number like :

> 15,87456213

How to get rid of all those decimals ? I want the command to return only the number 16

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the static Round method from the [math] class](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/17/powertip-use-powershell-to-round-numbers.aspx):

```
[Math]::Round((Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName localhost).TotalPhysicalMemory/1Gb)
```

Using this command on your example will return the expected number 16.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I'll try this asap and let you know ! But this already looks like the answer I'm looking for !

Comment: That works just fine, thanks a lot ! Never heard about this method before, will help for other scripts ! 10/10 will post again :D